Nethunter terminal does not open brave browser
I have rooted android and installed nethunter.
I installed brave browser through nethunter terminal. When I try to start brave browser on nethunter terminal, I got this error:
┌──(tes㉿localhost)-[~]
└─$ brave-browser
/usr/bin/brave-browser: line 36: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/brave-browser: line 37: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/brave-browser: line 39: 10834 Trace/breakpoint trap   "$HERE/brave" "$@"

